# std::type_info for array of runtime defined length

Tags: c++, arrays, typeid, typeinfo

When using `typeid(char[10])` one gets the `std::type_info` for `char[10]`.

Now I have the problem that I need to get `typeid(char[n])` where `n` isn't `constexpr`.

Is there a way to do that?

My current implementation just uses templates in a recursive way to generate calls from `typeid(char[1])` to `typeid(char[100])` and then choose the right call with a recursive function that stops at the right number.

While this works it only works for up to 100 and if I increase it much higher it will generate a lot of code or stop compiling because of too deep recursion

Are there other possibilities?

Naive implementation that would do what I want:

```
const std::type_info& getTypeInfoForCharArray(size_t len) 
{
  switch(len) 
  { 
    case 1: return typeid(char[1]);
    case 2: return typeid(char[2])
    case 3: return typeid(char[3])
    case 4: return typeid(char[4])
   ... 
  } 
}
```

**Background**

Now one might ask why I need such a function. To put it shortly, I have to integrate the definition of multiple structs from multiple DLLs where the lengths members can change and shouldn't require a recompilation of the code I work on. I need this to properly allocate and access the memory for those structs so I can call functions in those DLL.

Part of the implementation is a runtime type check for field access to avoid access violations because the C++ compiler can't check for those without knowing the struct at compile time. All this works well except for arrays.

If the answer to my question is "no, it can't be done" then I'll just have to treat arrays differently than other types.

Comment: Are you looking for `typeid(char[])`, perhaps?

Comment: C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: I'm not looking for variable length arrays but runtime access to the type_info of a fixed length array

Comment: uh.. I think i am starting to understand.. Is it the case that you do not have a `char[n]` but nevertheless you want to get the `typeid` for it?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. If I had it I could just use typeid(char[n]) anyways

Comment: Possible future [JIT template](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1609r0.html) might solve that issue... But currently, I don't see a way. swicth case equivalent can be generated with `std::index_sequence`.

Comment: You're exchanging data with a `std::type_index` followed by an object of that type, or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::integer_sequence`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Helper;

template <std::size_t ...L>
struct Helper<std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, L...>> {
    static const std::type_info &get(std::size_t len) {
        static const std::type_info *a[sizeof...(L)] = {&typeid(char[L])...};
        return *a[len];
    }
};

const std::type_info &getTypeInfoForCharArray(std::size_t len) {
    const std::size_t max = 10000;
    assert(len<=max);
    return Helper<std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, max+1>>::get(len);
}

int main() {
    auto &t = getTypeInfoForCharArray(10000);
    std::cout << t.name() << "\n";
}
```

This compiles in ~1 second with clang (with `max` size of 10,000).

Note, that this solution will generate all the `type_info` objects from 0 to `max`, which may need a significant amount of data (for this example, the resulting binary is ~1 MB), as the compiler needs to generate all `type_info` objects into the binary.

I think if you don't have the list of possible sizes beforehand, this is the best you can do
(or maybe you can consider some compiler dependent solution. Like exploiting the fact the we know of the format of `type_info::name()`, but this is a hacky solution. But maybe this is fine, if you use this feature for debugging only).

Comment: There is the alias `std::index_sequence` for `std::size_t`.

Comment: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array, so we might get rid of this one :-)

Comment: @Jarod42: True. But most compilers support zero-size arrays, and maybe there are no compilers which has a problem with `typeid(char[0])`. But if there were, it is pretty straightforward to modify my example.